# arabic data issue with mysql charecter

Tags: php, mysql

i have a php website with arabic language and the database consist of several tables
when i request data from the first table the browser shows it perfectly but when i request the data from other tables the data look like this "Ù…Ø­Ù…Ø¯"
notice : all the table are encoded in "UTF-8" and all the pages and the connection with the database depend on "UTF-8"
another notice : this problem was solved when i used (mysql 5) but when i use (mysql 4 or less) the problem come again 
How can i make the browser shows the data perfectly with (mysql 4)

Comment: Why are you even using MySQL 4? End-of-Life for version 4.1 was nearly 4 years ago

Comment: the host i use supports mysql 4

Comment: Then it's time to switch host

Comment: i don't think the problem from mysql cause the first table return data perfectly but the second one doesn't

Comment: while the first table shows the data perfectly you should check the encoding on the second table and check it also on each column cause each column also have an encoding attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try base_64 encoding the data before putting it into the db? It could be a special character causing corruption of the read.

Comment: base-64 doesn't support arabic
just utf-8 and cp1256

Comment: @Shnage how about uuencode: http://php.net/manual/en/function.convert-uuencode.php You might need to investigate some of the algorithms yourself, this idea, though, is to encode it into a neutral state for db usage.